Can't install nut-tree/nut-js on macOS
yarn add @nut-tree/nut-js

**yarn add v1.22.22**

warning package.json: No license field

info No lockfile found.

warning No license field

\[1/4\]   Resolving packages...

error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@nut-tree%2fnut-js: Not found

sudo npm i @nut-tree/nut-js -g

Password:

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@nut-tree%2fnut-js - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  '@nut-tree/nut-js@\*' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no package on package on npm called @nut-tree/nut-js.

npm ERR! 404  '@nut-tree/nut-js@*' is not in this registry.

To access nut.js packages you must purchase access to their private package registry.
